# Computer does not boot from DVD

Tags: installation, boot, boot-order

I'm new to Ubuntu.
My OS is XP service pack 3.
I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.3 32bit ISO file.
I burnt it to a DVD.
I put the DVD in my DVD drive and rebooted the computer.
The install routine does not start and the computer boots to my XP desktop.
I assumed the installer would automatically start.
Do I need to go into the BIOS and tell computer to boot from the DVD with the ISO file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you have to go into the bios,and change the boot order first priority to `DVD drive`.You can enter into the bios by pressing `F2` on startup.This key varies according to your device manufacturer's.